# How can I put a SearchView inside of a ToolBar with a height set to wrap_content without it disappearing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, searchview

I've noticed that if I place an `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` inside of an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with its height set to `wrap_content` that the `SearchView` behaves very strangely. It appears fine at first but then as soon is it gains focus it disappears and no longer takes up space in a layout. This can be resolved by setting an explicit height to the `Toolbar` but I'm trying to use `wrap_content` specifically because my use-case requires the `Toolbar` to resize dynamically.

It might also be worth mentioning that the `SearchView` is still functional after it disappears. If I add a `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` to the `SearchView` then I can observe that the query text is indeed being updated as I type. Neither this text nor any other part of the `SearchView` takes up space in the layout though and if you force it to be unobscured in the layout then it is still not visible.

This kind of seems like a bug in `SearchView` to me. Does anybody have some more insight into why it's happening or how to work around it?

Here's a working example of the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.me.MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/internalSearchView"
                app:queryHint="To..."
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: y cant u set match parent as the height , it would match the toolbar heights

Comment: That would work fine in this trivial example, but I want it to be `wrap_content` because I actually have additional dynamic views in there that change the effective height and require the `Toolbar` to expand. The buggy behavior can be observed without the extra views so I removed them from the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks like it should work... I have two suggestions.

1. If it doesn't interfere with your design goals, set `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"` on your toolbar. This may be desired anyway.
2. Try setting `android:layout_height="48dp"` on the SearchView.

Comment: Adding `minHeight` had no effect but specifying the `layout_height` explicitly worked! Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

No No No...
set the search view with these params:

```
<FrameLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <com.lapism.searchview.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/search_behavior"
                    app:search_version="menu_item"
                    app:search_version_margins="menu_item"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```